# Android onListItemClick exception: "java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor"

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, onitemclicklistener, android-cursor

As title says, it get this exception from the code I pasted below. I tried to make it work both with the uncommented code and also with the commented part insted of the IF block just before it. 
The error I get is: `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to android.database.Cursor` which I don't understand, since the item in the listview should exactly be a String! Any idea?

```
public class ListScoutActivity extends ListActivity {

    private DBHelper database;
    private ListView listav;
    private Cursor cursor;
    ArrayList<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_scout);

        database = new DBHelper(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db = database.getWritableDatabase();

        listav = this.getListView();
        listav.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        int codpartita;
        String team;

        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _codpartita as _id, team,  FROM partita ORDER BY _codpartita DESC", null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while ( !cursor.isAfterLast() ) {
            team = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("team"));  
            stringlist.add(team);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        if (cursor.getCount()>0) {
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(ListScoutActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, new String[]{"team"},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1}, 0);
            listav.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

//        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ListScoutActivity.this,
//                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, stringlist);
//        listav.setAdapter(adapter);
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Cursor cursor = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //.. other things..
    }
```

Comment: `Cursor cursor = (Cursor)l.getItemAtPosition(position);` your item is String, not cursor. Why do you get it as cursor?

Comment: So I should use something like 'String myString = (String) l.getItemAtPosition(position);' right?

Comment: `String item = l.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();`

Comment: I can't try until a few hours, but now that I think about it I should use a cursor because I'm extracting my informations from the ITEMS of the Listview, that is not a string but a "row" of string, or an array of strings. That's why I used this code.. The strange thing is that the same method was used elsewhere for another table and another listview, but it worked.. I tried to find the differences, and that's why I wrote the commented code too, but there are no differences..

Comment: Sadly it doesn't work even with your piece of code.